# Bibliography as a enumerate or itemize item

Tags: biblatex

I was wondering if it is possible to put citations in the `\enumerate` or `itemize`. Specifically, here is page that I have right now. [image: Screenshot of current output.]

In the section "Metadynamics", there are `enumerate` items that show the relevant paper. What I wanted to do is the put a single citation which as the format shown below as an enumerated item with a given `refs.bib`. For example, if things go well, the first enumerated item should be shown as something like:

(1) First paper of standard metadynamics

R Tycko et al.Molecular dynamics and the phase transition in solid C 60. 1991.doi:10.1103/PhysRevLett.67.1886

At the current stage, I know how to generate the bibliography as below, so I think I just need to know the method to put a citation as an enumerated item. A lot of thanks in advanced!

[image: Screenshot of current bibliography section.]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\fullcite` to obtain a full citation, within your main text. This is described within §3.8.6 of the [BibLaTeX](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) documentation.

For example, after an `\item`, on a new line, you can add `\fullcite{<bibkey>}`, where `<bibkey>` is the key of the entry you wish to cite for that item.